# Laravel test fails

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, laravel-5.4

I'm using [permission package](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission) from spatie.

It's working but my test keeps failing.

My test looks like this:

```
/** @test */
public function a_user_with_right_permission_can_update_company_profile()
{
    $role = create(Role::class, ['name' => 'super-admin']);
    $permission = create(Permission::class, ['name' => 'bewerk-bedrijf-instellingen']);

    $role->givePermissionTo($permission->name);
    $user = create(User::class)->assignRole($role->name);

    $user = $user->fresh();

    $this->signIn($user);

    $settings = [
        'name'          => 'Company',
        'email'         => 'info@example.com',
        'phone'         => '0623844932',
        'website'       => 'http://www.example.com',
        'description'   => 'A short description',
    ];

    $this->patch('/instellingen/bedrijf/profiel', $settings)
        ->assertSessionHas('status', 'Bedrijfsprofiel geupdatet!');

    $this->assertDatabaseHas('settings', $settings);
}
```

I receive this error message:

```
Failed asserting that two strings are equal.
--- Expected
+++ Actual
@@ @@
-'Bedrijfsprofiel geupdatet!'
+'Niet geautoriseerd!'
```

So It's telling me I'm not authorized to do this! But I've the correct permission. Because this is the middleware in that controller:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('permission:bewerk-bedrijf-instellingen');
}
```

When I remove the middleware the test is working. What could be going on here a cache issue?

**--Edit--**

```
 /** @test */
    public function a_user_with_right_permission_can_update_company_profile()
    {
        $permission = Permission::create([
            'name'  => 'bewerk-bedrijf-instellingen'
        ]);

        $role = Role::create([
            'name'  => 'super-admin'
        ]);

        $role->givePermissionTo($permission->name);

        $user = User::create([
            'name'                  => 'First',
            'last_name'             => 'Last',
            'email'                 => 'info@example.com',
            'password'              => 'secret',
            'password_confirmation' => 'secret',
            'function'              => 'Developer',
        ]);

        $user = $user->fresh();

        $this->signIn($user);

        $settings = [
            'name'          => 'Company',
            'email'         => 'info@example
.com',
            'phone'         => '0623844932',
            'website'       => 'http://www.example.com',
            'description'   => 'A short description',
        ];

        $this->patch('/instellingen/bedrijf/profiel', $settings)
            ->assertSessionHas('status', 'Bedrijfsprofiel geupdatet!');

        $this->assertDatabaseHas('settings', $settings);
    }
```

**Middleware**

```
 public function handle($request, Closure $next, $permission)
    {
        if (Auth::guest()) {
            return redirect('/');
        }

        if (!$request->user()->hasPermissionTo($permission)) {
            return back()
                ->with('status', 'Niet geautoriseerd!');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
```

When I `dd($request->user()->hasPermissionTo($permission));` in the middleware I receive false. When I `dd($request->user()->roles()->pluck('name'));` I receive `super-admin`.

Comment: `bewerk-bedrijf-instellingen` inside the code is mixing 2 languages... not a good choice. `$role->givePermissionTo` reads as it wants user instance not name of permission.

Comment: @Kyslik thanks but givePermissionTo expects a permission name. I've really no  idea why this is not working -_-

Comment: What is the create method?

Comment: @Kyslik it's a helper function for a factory:  `return factory($class, $times)->create($attributes);`

Comment: Mind adding all relevant code so people can simply copy-paste? I don't want to waste time making factories and such just add all relevant stuff into the question.

Comment: @Kyslik sure I've made an edit.

Comment: Check what status code has the response is it really 403? Testing session in Laravel is tricky a bit, read all these even old ones to get you started https://github.com/laravel/framework/search?q=assertSessionHas&type=Issues&utf8=%E2%9C%93

Comment: @Kyslik the response it because of my middleware (see my edit). I've tried: `$this->actingAs($user)->patch('/instellingen/bedrijf/profiel', $settings)
            ->assertSessionHas('status', 'Bedrijfsprofiel geupdatet!');` but that's not working.